# Branching schemas to local resolvers vs remote resolvers through configuration in Hasura

Tags: hasura

We are evaluating the use of Hasura for our platform. We have a unique need where sometimes our clients house their data with us and sometimes we call their APIs directly. We would like to have a common schema for our application layer and an ability to branch resolvers through configuration for each client so that the configuration controls whether to resolve a query or mutation locally or call a remote function to satisfy the query or mutation.

Is this possible in Hasura? if not, any suggestions how to do this well?

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with Hasura [Remote Schemas](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/remote-schemas/index.html). Since Hasura merges the remote schema and provides a unified GraphQL endpoint that you can query, the configuration controls are taken care of. Here's a simple [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01t4t2t4q1c).